# vue3: How to make one attribute of an external object reactive?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I have been looking for an elegant solution to this problem for a long time.

**MyClass.js**

```
class MyClass {
  // public 
  isReady = false
  isLoading = false
  isProcessing = false

  // private
  __source
  __buffer
  #otherPrivateVar
  // a lot of other stuff ...
}
```

I want to make only some **instance** attributes reactive and use them in a component.

In **Vue2** I use the private class attributes

```
MyClass
  // few public vars
  isReady = false

  // all other is private to hide it from vue reactivity
  #source
  #buffer
}
```

and use it in component like this

```
<template>
  ...
   <div v-if="myVariable.isReady">Ready to go</div>
   <div>wait a second ...</div>
  ...
</template>

export default {
  // ...
  data () {
    return {
      myVariable: new MyClass()
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a good solution but it works with **Vue2**. In **Vue3** I can't do this because it's using a Proxy and I'm getting the error:

```
AudioFile.js:131 TypeError: attempted to set private field on non-instance
    at _classPrivateFieldSet (classPrivateFieldSet.js:7)
```

So what's the best way to react when my object changes in Vue 3 (without using callbacks or making the whole object reactive without private attributes)?

Comment: Have you tried [Vue Class Component](https://class-component.vuejs.org/)?

Comment: @DimaMelnik This seems to no longer be an issue ([demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-class-instance-as-data-prop-in-vue-hk0lb?file=/src/App.vue)).

Comment: @tony19 the problem appears when a private variable is changed by calling class public method. i.e. @click="myVariable.publicMethod()" where is publicMethod() { this.#otherPrivateVar = value; }